# Derive backpropagation for PreLU

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, activation-function

I want to derive the back propagation functions for the Parametric Relu activation function which is defined as follows:

$$
h_a(x) = \text{max}(ax, x)
$$

I want to derive $ \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} $ which is a scalar, as $a$ is a scalar too.
I would start the derivation as:

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial Y} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial a}
$$

but I don't understand how this could yield a scalar in the end. The first term $\frac{\partial L}{\partial Y}$ is a matrix and $ \frac{\partial Y}{\partial a} $ is a matrix too. In solutions I found [online](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf) they just sum over all the elements in the resulting matrix, but I would think this double sum could be derived some way instead of just inserting the double sum.